# How to replace leading whitespace with tabs using grep or sed?

Tags: macos, sed, grep

I would like to replace all leading whitespace characters with an equal amount of tabs for every line in a file, using grep or sed. Each line has a few spaces followed by a dash and some text.

```
 -Line 1  
  -Line 2  
   -Line 3
```

Finding them is not a problem, but I don't see how to replace these characters using the backreferences. Something like:

`sed 's/^([\s]+)(-.*)/\1\2/' file.txt`

How can I solve this? Or is it even possible?

Comment: so you want to replace all the space characters with the same number of tabs ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your tab width, you might want to replace blocks of for example 4 or 8 spaces with tabs, like

```
sed 's/ \{4\}/\t/g' infile
```

or

```
sed 's/ \{8\}/\t/g' infile
```

This turns a file that looks like

```
$ cat infile
no space
 1 space
  2 spaces
   3 spaces
    4 spaces
     5 spaces
      6 spaces
       7 spaces
        8 spaces
         9 spaces
          10 spaces
           11 spaces
```

into this (replacing tabs with `^I` so we can see them):

```
$ sed 's/ \{4\}/\t/g' infile | cat -T
no space
 1 space
  2 spaces
   3 spaces
^I4 spaces
^I 5 spaces
^I  6 spaces
^I   7 spaces
^I^I8 spaces
^I^I 9 spaces
^I^I  10 spaces
^I^I   11 spaces
```

or this

```
$ sed 's/ \{8\}/\t/g' infile | cat -T
no space
 1 space
  2 spaces
   3 spaces
    4 spaces
     5 spaces
      6 spaces
       7 spaces
^I8 spaces
^I 9 spaces
^I  10 spaces
^I   11 spaces
```

The tab width can be parameterized (notice double quotes):

```
$ tw=7
$ sed "s/ \{$tw\}/\t/g" infile | cat -T
no space
 1 space
  2 spaces
   3 spaces
    4 spaces
     5 spaces
      6 spaces
^I7 spaces
^I 8 spaces
^I  9 spaces
^I   10 spaces
^I    11 spaces
```

Notice how this can be easily done also in vim, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104706/how-can-i-convert-spaces-to-tabs-in-vim-or-linux).

#### Spaces only at start of line

The commands above replace *any* group of four or eight spaces with a tab. If you want to only replace spaces at the start of a line, say for a file like this:

```
$ cat infile 
    4 spaces    word
     5 spaces    word
      6 spaces    word
       7 spaces    word
        8 spaces    word 
         9 spaces    word
```

you can use

```
$ sed ':a;s/^\(\t*\) \{4\}/\1\t/;/^\t* \{4\}/ba' infile | cat -T
^I4 spaces    word
^I 5 spaces    word
^I  6 spaces    word
^I   7 spaces    word
^I^I8 spaces    word 
^I^I 9 spaces    word
```

What this does:

```
# Label to branch to
:a

# Replace optional leading tabs followed by four spaces
# by the same amount plus one tabs
s/^\(\t*\) \{4\}/\1\t/

# If there are still four spaces after leading tabs, branch to a
/^\t* \{4\}/ba
```

#### Update

Turns out the question was actually about replacing spaces at the start of the line with a tab each.

For this input

```
0 spaces
 1 space
  2 spaces
   3 spaces
```

the following sed command works:

```
$ sed ':a;s/^\(\t*\) /\1\t/;ta' infile | cat -T
0 spaces$
^I1 space$
^I^I2 spaces$
^I^I^I3 spaces$
```

Explained:

```
:a                # Label to branch to
s/^\(\t*\) /\1\t/ # Capture tabs at start of line, replace next space with tab
ta                # Branches to :a if there was a substitution
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't entirely cover my case. I want to replace every space at the beginning by a tab, not every 4 or 8 spaces.

Comment: @ganzpopp I see - I've added a solution that does that.

Comment: The example `$ sed 's/^ \{4\}/\t/g' infile | cat -T` doesn't work as shown, at least not on Linux. It only replaces the first match.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx Right, the first few commands shouldn't use an anchor, I've removed it. The output didn't correspond to the commands shown, now it does.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and just use awk:

```
$ awk '{s=$0; sub(/[^ ].*/,"",s); gsub(/ /,"\t",s); sub(/^ +/,s)} 1' file
        -Line 1
                -Line 2
                        -Line 3
```