# How to replace spacing(apply new ~/.vimrc settings to) of an existing file in vim?

Tags: vim, replace, tabs, indentation, spaces

```
:set et tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2
```

Above was my initial setting of ~/.vimrc when I created a python(.py) file. I have 'expanded' all the tabs to spaces. My file has grown quite large now. Now I want all the tabs(that already exist in the file and those that I will add further), to have 4 spaces (which was 2 initially). So I tried:

```
:set et tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

in both, the current .py file and also by adding(editing) in my ~/.vimrc file. This only affects the changes that I make now. The rest of the file remains as such.
Any help appreciated. Help me accept vim I might be on the verge of quitting vim:)

Comment: See `:help :retab`.

Comment: ```:%/  /    /g````  is work-around that I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

This is Python, `:retab` and/or `gg=G` won't be enough.

May be (untested)... you could try to

1. force `setlocal noexpandtab`,
2. `:retab!` to force the use of tabs -- notice the bang (`!`)
3. change `setlocal sw=4` and `setlocal tabstop=4`,
4. re-`setlocal expandab`
5. `:retab`
6. restore tabstop to 8 -- i.e. just leave the default Python settings as they are.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The above works if the initially the expandtab was set to off i.e. ,
`:setlocal noexpandtab` and then the file was written. So, the tabs were registered as `^I` , can be checked - `:set list`. In my case tabs were registered as spaces(2 spaces). So `:retab` is not working in my case( I think). Once again thanks for your reply

Comment: If the file is indented with spaces, with a shift of 2 each time, if you set &sw and &ts to 2, expandtab to true, then with `:retab` the file shall be converted to use tab characters to indent. And the other way around when changing to noexpandtab.

Comment: My mistake. It should be  `:retab!`  to change from spaces to tabs. And `:retab` for the other way around

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9105889/13056176], here I found @Johnsyweb 's comment, this solved my problem. `:set noet ts=2 |%retab!` ; I think you meant the same. after that I changed `:set ts=4` as required. Thanks.